# Auto complete multiple results in textfield from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am new in php and ajax. I have search a lot from internet for this problem but in vain. I want to make an auto complete system just like this website: (http://www.zameen.com/). My problem is more simple than this website. My requirement is: "When I will enter something in text field, it will show the match results from database. When i will select one of those results then it will show in the same text field. I want to select multiple results and all results will show in the same text field."

Now my next question is: "how i will handle all these results in php variables and post them to my required file."

I am so much confused. Please give a simple solution because I am new in php and ajax.

You can see an image to understand my problem on this link: (http://mutaliapakistan.com/problem.png).

Comment: Questions like these are very hard to answer, because it is unclear where to start. Please show your own understanding of the problem by posting your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: I have added a picture to understand my problem. Its very simple. Just watch the image. I want to show multiple results in the same text field from my database using ajax

Comment: What you want is quite clear, what you did to try to solve it yourself is not. Please show your attempt at the problem.

Comment: I have tried to place my codes but codes are too big. I am new at stackoverflow as well. I am not able to put my codes its showing error.

Comment: do you know answer to my question ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give you a simple, working example of what you want:

this will be your livesearch.js file:

```
function showResult(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And this will be your livesearch.php file:

```
<?php
$hint="";
//get the q parameter from URL
if (!isset($key))$key = $_GET['q'];
//include the mysql conn script
require_once ('mysql_connect.php');

//just change the selects here to what you want/ need.
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table_name WHERE display='1' AND (name LIKE '%$key%' OR description LIKE '%$key%') LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($result_row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$found = $result_row[12];
if (strlen($found)>25)
{
$found = substr($found, 0, 25) . '...';
}
$hint = $hint."<div id='search_result'><a href=\"http://example.com/index.php?category=$result_row[3]&name=$result_row[1]&id=$result_row[0]\">".$found."</a></div>";
}
// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint == "")
  {
  $response = "No results";
  }
else
  {
  $response = $hint;
  }
//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

And now finally to the page that you want to have the seach in it add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="livesearch.js"></script>
<div class="search">
<form name="frm_search" id="frm_search" method="get" action="advanced_search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Search" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)"/>
<input type="submit" name="search_go" id="search_go" value="↵"/>
</form>
<div id="livesearch" style="margin-left:3px;background-color:#fff;text-align:left;">
</div>
</div>
```

I hope it's clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You did the live search very well. You are redirecting the single result to an other page. But first, i want to grape all the results in the same text box and then redirect page after submit the form.

Comment: then return the value of the query as the value of your text box.
change <div id="livesearch" style="margin-left:3px;background-color:#fff;text-align:left;"> to <textarea id='livesearch'></textarea>
and in livesearch.php change the line with $hint = $hint. ... to
$hint = $hint."$result_row[0]$result_row[1]$result_row[2]";

Comment: sorry trian i am unable to do that because i m new in php. can u chat with me on apptrekker.pk@gmail.com ???

Comment: Sure. I'll send you an e-mail right now.

Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:
apptrekker.pk@gmail.com
The recipient's e-mail address was not found in the recipient's e-mail system. Microsoft Exchange will not try to redeliver this message for you. Please check the e-mail address and try resending this message, or provide the following diagnostic text to your system administrator.
The following organization rejected your message: mx.google.com.

Comment: send me ur facebook link. we can chat there

Comment: [here](https://www.facebook.com/Traian.Tatic) it is..

Comment: sent u message on fb